# How to store large files on Fat32

Tags: fat32

I wanted to store a large video file on a FAT32 drive (~18 GB), but I discovered that this isn't simply possible due to limitations of the file system.

Is there a simple tool that exists for splitting the file into smaller parts that are storable, then reassembling them when I would like to retrieve the archived file?

Or is there a better way of storing large files on FAT32?

Comment: Any archive utility (eg, 7zip) can do this, with or without compression.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know - I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Ok, 7zip will do it - however it takes about 5-10 times longer than the script below. Anyway, I thought it might be helpful.

Comment: Is this an external disk that needs to be mounted both on Windows and non-Windows systems? If not, why not just convert to a modern file system? Use whatever happens to be the default for the system that the drive is connected to.

Comment: *> Ok, 7zip will do it - however it takes about 5-10 times longer than the script below.*  Even *without* compression? `o.O`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most file archivers, such as [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), WinZip, and WinRAR, allow you to split an archive across multiple files. If speed is important, you can try disabling the compression part of the program.

On GNU/Linux systems, you can use the [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) and [cat](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cat-invocation.html) programs from the coreutils package (e.g. `split -b 4294967295 FOO /media/FATDISK/BAR` to split FOO into BARaa, BARab, ... and `cat /media/FATDISK/BAR?? > FOO` to reassemble it). Mac OS X's command line `split` utility works in the same way.

Answer (score 5):

**If you are looking for a quick solution to this, please see the other answers featuring `7zip` or `split`.** This is more of a *fun* solution.

I ended up writing a small Python 2 script to achieve this.

---

```
# Author: Alex Finkel 
# Email: alex@finkel.net

# This program splits a large binary file into smaller pieces, and can also 
# reassemble them into the original file.

# To split a file, it takes the name of the file, the name of an output 
# directory, and a number representing the number of desired pieces.

# To unsplit a file, it takes the name of a directory, and the name of an 
# output file.

from sys import exit, argv
from os import path, listdir

def split(file_to_split, output_directory, number_of_chunks):
    f = open(file_to_split, 'rb')
    assert path.isdir(output_directory)
    bytes_per_file = path.getsize(file_to_split)/int(number_of_chunks) + 1
    for i in range(1, int(number_of_chunks)+1):
        next_file = open(path.join(output_directory, str(i)), 'wb')
        next_file.write(f.read(bytes_per_file))
        next_file.close()
    f.close()
                
def unsplit(directory_name, output_name):
    assert path.isdir(directory_name)
    files = map(lambda x: str(x), sorted(map(lambda x: int(x), listdir(directory_name))))
    out = open(output_name, 'wb')
    for file in files:
        f = open(path.join(directory_name, file), 'rb')
        out.write(f.read())
        f.close()
    out.close()
        
    
if len(argv) == 4:
    split(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3])
elif len(argv) == 3:
    unsplit(argv[1], argv[2])
else:
    print "python split_large_file.py file_to_split output_directory number_of_chunks"
    print "python split_large_file.py directory name_of_output_file"
    exit()
```

Comment: -1 for [reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

Comment: +1 for [DIY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_it_yourself).

Comment: +1 for sharing their work that might be useful to someone else in the future. Plus, if no-one ever re-invents wheels, *one day no-one will know how to invent wheels*.

Comment: reinventing the wheel is good if one have time, but it's not the solution for a right-away result when you already have to tools available

Answer (score 4):

Another option: use the `split` command from GNU Coreutils:

`split --bytes=4G infile /media/FAT32drive/outprefix`

to split the file into 4 GB chunks and save the chunks to the output drive.

The original file can be recovered by concatenating the chunks (with filenames sorted alphabetically).

For usage info, see the [`split` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html).

Coreutils, including `split`, should be installed by default on Linux and Mac OS X. On Windows, it's [available from GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), or from Cygwin.

Comment: great - worked with cygwin in windows - very straightforward - if you wanted to update with the recombine command that would be great, but I will look it up and suggest an edit if you don't!

Comment: commented too soon - for me I needed to put --bytes=3G else it failed as 4G hit the file size limit --- but with 3G it worked a treat (well)

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly this problem and solved it using help from the answers already posted, but not one  of them described the method exactly.

I used

`split --bytes=3G infile /media/FAT32drive/outprefix`

which save infile to multiple files named outprefixaa, outprefixab, outprefixac etc. with a maximum size of 3GB - when I tried to use 4GB on Fat 32 it failed.

to recombine the files I used

`cat /media/FAT32drive/outprefix?? > infile`

To give more specific details I did this in windows, but using a cygwin window. So the file path in my case for the external FAT32 harddisk was `/cydrive/e/`

Answer (score 0):

For creating files with maximum allowed size on vfat (2³²-1 bytes), use the following command (in bash):

```
split --bytes=$((2**32-1)) infile /media/FAT32drive/outprefix
```

or, if you don't want to use bash's inline math:

```
split --bytes=4294967295 infile /media/FAT32drive/outprefix
```

The '--bytes=4G' fails, because 4G equals to 2³² bytes, which is exactly one byte more than the maximum file size on vFAT.